# How to disable an extension for one page in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

There is a conflict between two installed extentions in one page. I want to disable one of the extentions only for this specific Page.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Maybe somehow in Backend Templates?

Answer (score 1):

On the page where you want to disable the extension you can create a template where you disable the extension by TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_badextension >
tt_content.list.20.tx_badextension >
```

This works recursive, that means all sub-pages of the page where this snippet is included in a template are concerned too. If you want to enable the plugin on a sub-page again, you've to include there the TypoScript of the extension.

It's also possible to include the extension's TypoScript only on a few pages and not in the root-page. But the configuration is always inherited and has to be inversed if the plugin shall be activated or deactivated on sub-pages.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no way. Extensions can only disable for the complete TYPO3 installation.

EDIT:
Here is a way to disable this extension for a single pages like news page with typoscript.

```
// Skip tx_jhopengraphprotocol for single news view, as EXT:news adds dedicated og-properties
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    temp.tx_jhopengraphprotocol >
    page.669 >
[global]
```

Comment: one of the extensions is my own and the other one is jh_opengraphprotocol. In my extension I create dynamically the open graph tags. Therefore I have multiple og:Tags on the page !!!

Comment: i had looked into the jh_opengraphprotocol code and found a solution. I post it in my first answer post ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the setup.txt https://github.com/jonathanheilmann/ext-jh_opengraphprotocol/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt

You should be able to deactivate it with

```
temp.tx_jhopengraphprotocol >
page.669 >
```

In your TypoScript for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way the extensions are included you might be able to deactivate the rendering of one extension.

Most extensions are configured in typoscript, where you can clear the corresponding part in an extension template (or TS condition) for your page.

either you deactivate the extension specific part (`plugins.my_extension >`)
or the inclusion in the page rendering (`page.100 >` if the extension was included like `page.100 < plugin.my_extension`)
or clear the configuration for plugins as subtree of tt_content `tt_content.list.20.my_extension >`

The way is dependent on your extension and might fail if the inclusion is done in other ways (e.g. hooks, signals)