# TYPO3: Extensions activated for specific sites

Tags: typo3

Is it possible that some specific Extensions are just usable for a specific set of sites (defined in page as "is site root")?

Why i the Permissions would not fit my needs: I have editors (BE Group) that have access to all sites, but some pages should not have the option to select specific Plugins (and page Templates from another sites).

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693266/how-to-disable-an-extension-for-one-page-in-typo3/

Comment: I don´t just want it to disable it in frontend, i don´t want it to be selectable in the backend.

Comment: Ok, that's another aspect.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no such option in TYPO3.

But there are workarounds:

1. there are extensions which restrict specific contentelements in columns ([ext:gridelements](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements/), [ext:content_defender](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender/)).
   These Extensions enable/disable CEs columnwise in the BE-layout definition.

while you can select plugins with ext:content_defender,

2. you otherwise can wrap a plugin into a specific own contentelement. Then you can disable contentelements pagewise by page-TSconfig (keep in mind that you need to disable general plugins)